# Rewrite predicate

Tags: prolog

```
scal(_, _, [], []).
scal(Lista, [H|T], Wszystkie, [(X-Y)|Wynik]) :-
    wez_poz(H, Lista, (X-Y)),
    select(X, Wszystkie, W2),
    select(Y, W2, W3),
    scal(Lista, T, W3, Wynik).
```

Does any one know how to rewrite that predicate to be completely different but works same?
`wez_poz(H, List, (X-Y))` unifies `X` and `Y` with position of `H` in `Lista`, and `Wszystkie` is list of all positions in matrix, for example wszystkie for `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]` is `[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]`

Comment: well homework a little cos i wrote that predicate but i was thinking if there is any way to make it faster or more simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pair of select/3 is used to *search* and extract elements from `Wszystkie`, thus could be combined in a single predicate, with a little gain (I presume):

```
scal(_, _, [], []).
scal(Lista, [H|T], Wszystkie, [(X-Y)|Wynik]) :-
    wez_poz(H, Lista, (X-Y)),
    find_pair(Wszystkie, X, Y, W3),
    scal(Lista, T, W3, Wynik).

find_pair([X|Wszystkie], X, Y, W3) :-
  !, select(Y, Wszystkie, W3).
find_pair([Y|Wszystkie], X, Y, W3) :-
  !, select(X, Wszystkie, W3).
find_pair([H|Wszystkie], X, Y, [H|W3]) :-
  find_pair(Wszystkie, X, Y, W3).
```

A better optimization could be using a sorted data structure for `Wszystkie`. For instance SWI-Prolog offers [ordered sets](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.17%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/ordsets.html%27%29%29) or [red black trees](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/rbtrees.pl). Using rb_tree search time will be reduced to O(log(N)), but you must account for sorting and more memory overhead.